# How do I make a correlation matrix for each subset of a column of my pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pearson-correlation

Here’s the head of my dataframe:

There are 100 different loggers and 10 different years. I want to subset the table by logger and find the Pearson correlation values for year by avg_max_temp, avg_min_temp, and tot_precipitation for each logger. Because there are 100 loggers, I’d expect the resulting dataframe to have 100 rows of 3 output columns as well as a column for the logger ID..

Here’s how I would do this analysis for all the data combined:

```
# Create a new dataframe with the correlation values
corr_df = pd.DataFrame(df.corr(method='pearson'))

corr_df.drop(['year', 'yield'], axis=1, inplace=True)
corr_df.drop(['avg_max_temp', 'avg_min_temp', 'tot_precipitation','yield'], axis=0, inplace=True)
# Print the dataframe
corr_df.head()
```

However, I can’t figure out how to do this for each of the 100 dataloggers. Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through a `groupby` object to iterate through each portion of the `df` with a unique `logger`, and extract the Pearson correlation coefficients for each group, concatenating them together into your final `corr_df` DataFrame.

```
corr_df = pd.DataFrame()

for group, df_group in df.groupby('logger'):
    # Create a new dataframe with the correlation values
    group_corr_df = pd.DataFrame(df_group.corr(method='pearson'))

    group_corr_df.drop(['year', 'yield'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    group_corr_df.drop(['avg_max_temp', 'avg_min_temp', 'tot_precipitation','yield'], axis=0, inplace=True)
    group_corr_df['logger'] = group
    corr_df = pd.concat([corr_df, group_corr_df])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply here. This is almost there. It gives me a df with the three output columns. Do you know if there is a way to also include the logger's id as a fourth column? Or in other words, the string saying what group each trio of data corresponds with?

Comment: @Trev we can add a new column called `logger` to `group_corr_df` just before we concat

Comment: Thank you @Derek O, that's a huge help. Is there any way you could explain how the loop works? What are group and df_group referring to in the original groupby dataframe?

Comment: @Trev sure, i'm happy to explain a bit further. you are looping through portions of the dataframe where `logger = {each unique logger value}`. so if the first logger value is `'011072.txt'`, then on the first iteration of the loop, `group = '011072.txt'` and `df_group = df[df['logger'] == '011072.txt']`